# The latest trends in designing windows based desktop application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, silverlight, desktop-application

I have an application written in C#, using .Net 4.0 framework. As the application is kind of an old application, so its using window forms. The application is very simple for now, it doesn't have high graphical interface like using WPF and Silverlight. I have now decided to move the application to the next level, the latest, one using current trends and great user interface. What are my options of improving this application design wise, performance wise and looks wise? Like using WPF, MS Silverlight or any other cool technology out there?

I kinda more need ideas what can I do to get to high tech application? Some examples of some cool applications would be also appreciated.

A little about the application:

Its a windows desktop application, using Access as a database used for some finance analysis.

If more information needed? Please let me know.

Comment: This isn't really the forum for this kind of question. Really we need to see what you've already tried to do, and then we can try and help with code when you get stuck. "What cool application UI can I copy" is kind of a wide ranging topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: Id say WPF is all you need technology-wise. Its really neat, i love the looks of it and its quite easy to use (especially with Expression Blend!)

On a side note:

The big issue here will be designing a good interface, not using "shinier" buttons. Currently, the UI design is getting more and more elements to it, changing to UX design. You can read about it if you google, a few links to start with:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx

http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/industryinsights/solutions/pdfs/Forrester_Best_Prac_In_User_Exp.pdf

http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/creative-vision.html - this is about Android, but it can and should be transferred to a desktop environment

Ill use a little metaphore: Youre asking us "what kind of paint should I use for my masterpiece painting that will put Leonardo Da Vinci to shame?". Are you sure you already know what and how to do with that paint? Some artists drew masterpieces using only a single pencil, others couldnt do anything of value despite using the best tools available.